# Deserialization of subclass Implementations

Tags: java

say i have two implementations of one abstract class

```
Abstract
 /  \
A1   A2
```

i have an object wit a list of Abstract which can contain A1 and A2 objects

```
O1 -> List<Abstract>
```

I serialize the the O1 object without a problem.
When I deserialize the deserializer does not know which class it should deserialize to for the content of the list (A1 or A2).
Is there a nice way to solve this problem.

An example that i could think of would be an object containing a list of numbers with the content of Integer and Float objects.

If i need to give more information please let me know so i can extend the question.

Comment: Your serialization procedure should have all the informations available about that object and store also meta-info about its actual class. Doing so, the deserialization procedure will know how to correctly deserialize each object